# Haiku Generator Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program that generates random Haikus. My plan is to have the program read in files that contain specified number of syllable nouns, verbs, and adjectives, but I am having a problem with the coding. Right now it looks like this:

```
package poetryproject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class PoetryProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        Random gen = new Random();

        Scanner adjectivesFile = new Scanner(new File("AdjectivesFile.dat"));
        Scanner nounFile = new Scanner(new File("NounFile.dat"));
        Scanner verbFile = new Scanner(new File("VerbFile.dat"));

        int adjectiveCount = adjectivesFile.nextInt();
        String[] adjectiveList = new String[adjectiveCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < adjectiveCount; i++) {
            adjectiveList[i] = adjectivesFile.nextLine();
        }
        adjectivesFile.close();

        int nounCount = nounFile.nextInt();
        String[] nounList = new String[nounCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < nounCount; i++) {
            nounList[i] = nounFile.nextLine();
        }
        nounFile.close();

        int verbCount = verbFile.nextInt();
        String[] verbList = new String[verbCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < verbCount; i++) {
            verbList[i] = verbFile.nextLine();
        }
        verbFile.close();

        for (int count = 1; count <= 1; count++) {
           System.out.printf("The %s %s \n",       adjectiveList[gen.nextInt(adjectiveList.length)]);
        }
        for (int count = 1; count <= 1; count++) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s \n", nounList[gen.nextInt(nounList.length)]);
        }
        for (int count = 1; count <= 1; count++) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s \n", verbList[gen.nextInt(verbList.length)]);
        }
     }
}
```

For my output I am only getting the "The" adjective part. Why is this?

Oh yeah, and I'm only working on getting the first line to print correctly for the moment.

Comment: Where is `gen` defined?

Comment: Random gen = new Random();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified a second a argument for the System.out.printf it would generate 
cannot find symbol error at line:

```
System.out.printf("The %s %s \n",adjectiveList[gen.nextInt(adjectiveList.length)]);
                          ^
```

Removing the second format specifier and writing it like:

```
System.out.printf("The %s\n",       adjectiveList[gen.nextInt(adjectiveList.length)]);
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The format specifier of the first `printf()` doesn't match the arguments:

```
System.out.printf("The %s %s \n", adjectiveList[gen.nextInt(adjectiveList.length)]);
```

This will throw a [`MissingFormatArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/MissingFormatArgumentException.html), prematurely ending your program after the adjective part is printed.

Comment: The method is waiting for 2 arguments to format and you're only passing 1, the adjective from your list. Either remove a `%s` or add another argument after the adjective.

Comment: Well dang that was easy. Thanks!